# Excel: how to add random decimals to numbers with a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have a list of gps coordinates for a map that we need to randomize a bit as we cannot provide the exact addresses. I would like to shorten the original coordinates (that is the easy part as I just can use one of the buttons in Excel to move decimal places) but then I would have some duplicates that would overlap on the map.

How do I add random two digits at the end of each number?

The full coordinates would something like this :

> -41.12582016  175.0709534

I can shorten this to:

> -41.125   175.070

And then I need to generate two more decimal places to randomize this (in case of double ups). So the above would look like this for example:

> -41.12512 175.07034

How would i do this for both longitude and latitude columns for hundreds of entries at once with a macro?

Comment: Using the decrease decimal buttons does not change the value, it only truncates the display. You should use `ROUND()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a Macro:

```
=A1 & RANDBETWEEN(0;9) & RANDBETWEEN(0;9)
```

[image]

If you really want to do it in VBA, iterate over the cells with the following (here it only looks at A1):

```
Range("A1") = Range("A1") & Int((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1) & Int((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
```